# The duration of the event must be shorter than how frequently it occurs error in wp8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Can anybody Please explain the reason for coming this error message in the below scenario in native calender app in Windows Phone 8.1,

How long >>. Select Custom 
Start Date 01 April 2015 12:00 Am 
End Date : 01 June 2015 12: 02 Am 
Occurs >> Every day

Error Message : The duration of the event must be shorter than how frequently it occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception message seems pretty clear to me. Your event is defined to start on April 1, 2015 and continue until June 1, 2015. That's a total duration of two months, or 61 days.

You've specified that the recurrence of the event is *every day*.

Sixty one days is (much) longer than one day, which is not permitted. In other words, before an event can recur, the previous instance of the event must already have completed.

If you want the operation to succeed, either specify an event that lasts shorter than a day, or specify a recurrence interval that is longer than 61 days.

Comment: This is correct and was my misunderstanding to. However the functionality I was originally looking for doesn't seem to exist. Perhaps the OP like I was trying to build a reoccurring event between the start and end dates. NOT a reoccurring event with the duration of the start and end date. This was my confusion.

Comment: I have also got the same issue. The thing is when you create new teams meeting in outlook and go to Appointment Recurrence popup then there is Appointment Time section. The may be the case when you schedule meeting for 45 min then in the Duration dropdown 45 minutes option is not there. You need to put manually 45 min there. (Just one example where I got error as earlier by default it was showing some days)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Meeting Icon instead of Appointment.
I had the same issue while I created a Appointment instead of a Meeting.
Once I changed to Meeting, the invite was successfully sent.